# I'm struggling to get around the "Objects are not valid as a React child" error

Tags: json, reactjs, xml, axios

Apologies in advance, I see that others have had the same issue but I'm really struggling to make their solutions work in my instance.

I have Axios bringing in XML from a local source, which I have xml-js convert to JSON, when then gets parsed and pushed into an array in this.state.data.

I can't seem to find a way to map it to even display the raw output on the page.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import moment from 'moment';
import Header from './components/layout/Header';
import Main from './components/layout/Main';
import Footer from './components/layout/Footer';

const convert = require('xml-js');

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      lastUpdate: '',
    }
  }

  async axiosFunc() {
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' }
      }

      const res = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8088/API/', config);
      console.log("Checking");
      const parsedJson = JSON.parse(convert.xml2json(res.data, { compact: false, spaces: 2 })
      );
      
      let arrJson = [];
      arrJson.push(parsedJson);
      console.log("Arr = " + arrJson);
      const updateTime = new Date();
      this.setState({
        data: arrJson,
        lastUpdate: moment(updateTime).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm:ss "),
      })
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("ERROR: " + e);
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.axiosFunc();
    setInterval(() => {
      this.axiosFunc();
    }, 10000)
  };

  render() {        
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header lastUpdate={this.state.lastUpdate} />
        <Main data={this.state.data} />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Main.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
    
  render() {
    let rawData = this.props.data;
    console.log("rawData = " + JSON.stringify(rawData)); // Shows entire JSON
    let reformatData = rawData.map(obj => {
      let rObj = {}
      rObj[obj.key] = obj.value
      return rObj
    }) // This reformatData idea came from MDN
    console.log("reformatData = " + JSON.stringify(reformatData)) // Shows an empty object in an empty array, unsure why
    console.log("this.props.data = " + this.props.data) // Shows entire JSON output
    console.log("elements? = " + reformatData.elements) // undefined
    console.log("Props: " + JSON.stringify(this.props.data)) // Empty object
    return (
      <div>
        <h6>
          {reformatData.elements} // I Thought this would display the entire JSON output
        </h6>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Example JSON output:

```
[{
    "elements": [{
        "type": "element",
        "name": "statcaster",
        "elements": [{
            "type": "element",
            "name": "version",
            "elements": [{
                "type": "text",
                "text": "23.0.0.62"
            }]
        }, {
            "type": "element",
            "name": "edition",
            "elements": [{
                "type": "text",
                "text": "4K"
            }]
        }, {
            "type": "element",
            "name": "inputs",
            "elements": [{
                "type": "element",
                "name": "input",
                "attributes": {
                    "key": "f49ee773-b122-4cf7-8f35-6919a19ab97f",
                    "number": "1",
                    "type": "Blank",
                    "title": "Blank",
                    "shortTitle": "Blank",
                    "state": "Paused",
                    "position": "0",
                    "duration": "0",
                    "loop": "False"
                },
                "elements": [{
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "Blank"
                }]
            }, {
                "type": "element",
                "name": "input",
                "attributes": {
                    "key": "ee0649f9-b149-4f8a-9d1b-410bbc588759",
                    "number": "2",
                    "type": "Blank",
                    "title": "Blank",
                    "shortTitle": "Blank",
                    "state": "Paused",
                    "position": "0",
                    "duration": "0",
                    "loop": "False"
                },
                "elements": [{
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "Blank"
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "type": "element",
            "name": "overlays",
            "elements": [{
                "type": "element",
                "name": "overlay",
                "attributes": {
                    "number": "1"
                }
            }, {
                "type": "element",
                "name": "overlay",
                "attributes": {
                    "number": "2"
                }
            }, {
                "type": "element",
                "name": "overlay",
                "attributes": {
                    "number": "3"
                }
            }, {
                "type": "element",
                "name": "overlay",
                "attributes": {
                    "number": "4"
                }
            }, {
                "type": "element",
                "name": "overlay",
                "attributes": {
                    "number": "5"
                }
            }, {
                "type": "element",
                "name": "overlay",
                "attributes": {
                    "number": "6"
                }
            }]
        }, {
            "type": "element",
            "name": "preview",
            "elements": [{
                "type": "text",
                "text": "2"
            }]
        }, {
            "type": "element",
            "name": "active",
            "elements": [{
                "type": "text",
                "text": "1"
            }]
        }, {
            "type": "element",
            "name": "fadeToBlack",
            "elements": [{
                "type": "text",
                "text": "False"
            }]
        }, {
            "type": "element",
            "name": "transitions",
            "elements": [{
                "type": "element",
                "name": "transition",
                "attributes": {
                    "number": "1",
                    "effect": "Fade",
                    "duration": "500"
                }
            }, {
                "type": "element",
                "name": "transition",
                "attributes": {
                    "number": "2",
                    "effect": "Fly",
                    "duration": "1000"
                }
            }, {
                "type": "element",
                "name": "transition",
                "attributes": {
                    "number": "3",
                    "effect": "Merge",
                    "duration": "250"
                }
            }, {
                "type": "element",
                "name": "transition",
                "attributes": {
                    "number": "4",
                    "effect": "FlyRotate",
                    "duration": "1000"
                }
            }]
        }, {
            "type": "element",
            "name": "recording",
            "elements": [{
                "type": "text",
                "text": "False"
            }]
        }, {
            "type": "element",
            "name": "external",
            "elements": [{
                "type": "text",
                "text": "True"
            }]
        }, {
            "type": "element",
            "name": "streaming",
            "elements": [{
                "type": "text",
                "text": "False"
            }]
        }, {
            "type": "element",
            "name": "playList",
            "elements": [{
                "type": "text",
                "text": "False"
            }]
        }, {
            "type": "element",
            "name": "multiCorder",
            "elements": [{
                "type": "text",
                "text": "False"
            }]
        }, {
            "type": "element",
            "name": "fullscreen",
            "elements": [{
                "type": "text",
                "text": "False"
            }]
        }, {
            "type": "element",
            "name": "audio",
            "elements": [{
                "type": "element",
                "name": "master",
                "attributes": {
                    "volume": "100",
                    "muted": "False",
                    "meterF1": "0",
                    "meterF2": "0",
                    "headphonesVolume": "100"
                }
            }, {
                "type": "element",
                "name": "busA",
                "attributes": {
                    "volume": "100",
                    "muted": "False",
                    "meterF1": "0",
                    "meterF2": "0"
                }
            }, {
                "type": "element",
                "name": "busB",
                "attributes": {
                    "volume": "100",
                    "muted": "False",
                    "meterF1": "0",
                    "meterF2": "0"
                }
            }, {
                "type": "element",
                "name": "busC",
                "attributes": {
                    "volume": "100",
                    "muted": "False",
                    "meterF1": "0",
                    "meterF2": "0"
                }
            }, {
                "type": "element",
                "name": "busD",
                "attributes": {
                    "volume": "100",
                    "muted": "False",
                    "meterF1": "0",
                    "meterF2": "0"
                }
            }, {
                "type": "element",
                "name": "busE",
                "attributes": {
                    "volume": "100",
                    "muted": "False",
                    "meterF1": "0",
                    "meterF2": "0"
                }
            }, {
                "type": "element",
                "name": "busF",
                "attributes": {
                    "volume": "100",
                    "muted": "False",
                    "meterF1": "0",
                    "meterF2": "0"
                }
            }, {
                "type": "element",
                "name": "busG",
                "attributes": {
                    "volume": "100",
                    "muted": "False",
                    "meterF1": "0",
                    "meterF2": "0"
                }
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

I would like to be able to map the entire JSON, and get values from keys dynamically as they change.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: HTML doesn't know anything about JSON, or JS objects, it just knows strings. So you'd have to do `{  JSON.stringify(yourHugeObject, false, 2) }` at the very least (the added 2 arguments to force pretty indentation), and you probably want to put that in something that preserves `white-space` (like a `<pre>`, or something with explicit `white-space` CSS).

Comment: Should that be done at the initial data stage at the convert.xml2json stage, or at the display stage?

Comment: That depends entirely on you and your needs. The only thing the browser cares about is that by the time it shows the data, it's HTML elements and string content. There's not all that much value in seeing a giant JSON block, so I'd recommend not even doing this and instead writing a `renderData()` that turns your JSON into easy to digest presentational HTML (tables, trees, whatever) and then call that in your render function as `<section id="view-data"><h2>explore the data</h2>{ this.renderData() }</section>` or the like.